# Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f(x) \geq 0$, and that $\int_{a}^{b} f\ = 0$. Show that $f(x) =0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f(x) \geq 0$, and that $\int_{a}^{b} f\ = 0$. Show that $f(x) =0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$.

I began the proof by first justifying that $f(c) > 0$ for some $c \in [a,b]$. As $f$ is now continuous at that c, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\|f(x) - f(c)\| < \epsilon$. I chose $\epsilon = f(c)/2$ and noticed that $f(x) \geq f(c)/2$.

I am also having trouble with going further and applying the fact that $\int_{a}^{b} f\ = 0$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The inequality $f(x)\geq f(c)/2$ is true on some small-enough interval $I=[c-\delta,c+\delta]$. So, the function $g(x)$ defined to be $f(c)/2$ on $I$ and zero elsewhere, satisfies $f(x)\geq g(x)$. Integrate on both sides and you get that $\int_{a}^{b}f\geq \int_{a}^{b}g=\delta f(c)>0$.